# React Native - expo getCurrentPositionAsync not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, location

So I'm trying to get the users current co-oridnates from expo-location and testing it using the expo client on my android phone. The code below logs status as approved but latitude and longitude don't get updated and on iphone I get the following error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 400]
> at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
> at node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:16:9 in settle
> at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:52:6 in handleLoad
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:601:4 in setReadyState
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:396:6 in __didCompleteResponse
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter.js:135:10 in EventEmitter#emit

Code:

```
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState();
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState();
    const getLocationAsync = async () => {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    
        if (status === 'granted') {
            console.log('Approved!');
            return Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
        } else {
           console.log('Rejected!');
           throw new Error('Location permission not granted');
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const location = getLocationAsync();
        setLatitude(location.latitude);
        setLongitude(location.longitude);
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getLocationAsync` is promise function.

you can change this code

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    
        if (status === 'granted') {
           console.log('Approved!');
           const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
           setLatitude(location.latitude);
           setLongitude(location.longitude);
        } else {
           console.log('Rejected!');
           throw new Error('Location permission not granted');
        }
    })();
  }, []);
```

Comment: sorry, this didn't work either, I'm getting the same response